# Can't access button in nested button control with jQuery

Tags: jquery, controls, click, nested

I'm trying to submit a form from JavaScript when a user hits the `[ENTER]` key.  `.submit` won't work because we have multiple buttons in our form.

The `DDLClientName` drop down list resides in our `aspnetForm` form.  There is another custom control in this form called `SaveCancelDelete`.  This control (*.ascx) contains all of our buttons.

What I want to do is cause the click event to fire for one of the buttons.  What I have below works, but it's a little hacked up.  I tried the code below that with the nested `ClientID` callbacks, but that doesn't seem to work.  I'm looking for the cleanest approach.

```
    jQuery(this.Elements.DDLClientName).keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            //jQuery("#aspnetForm").submit();
            jQuery("#ctl00_body_QuickDataEntryEditor_SaveCancelDelete_BtnNonAuthenticated1").click();
        }
    });
```

This doesn't seem to work:

```
jQuery('#<%=SaveCancelDelete.ClientID %>').jQuery('#<%=BtnNonAuthenticated1.ClientID %>').click();
```

Comment: What is rendered to the page with <%=BtnNonAuthenticated1.ClientID %>? Also can you provide an example of the HTML that is rendered to the page for the QuickDataEntryEditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example needs to be `.find()` instead of `.jQuery()`

```
jQuery('#<%=SaveCancelDelete.ClientID %>').find('#<%=BtnNonAuthenticated1.ClientID %>').click();
```

but since it's already an ID, you don't really need to have both, this should work too:

```
jQuery('#<%=BtnNonAuthenticated1.ClientID %>').click();
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get those to work.. when I did an alert for the first piece of code you had with .val() at the end of it instead of .click(), it said "undefined".

Comment: Strange.. I think my JavaScript pseudo class was cached, and never got updated.  Now it works great!  Both work, but I like the first one better in case we introduce another control.  It shows what control it's located in.  Thanks much!